# How to create SEO Friendly categories using CakePHP and TreeBehaviors?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I need to store hierarchical data in a mysql table. I'm using CakePHP 2.2.4.

I found this good behavior in CakePHP doc:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html

I have understood how to use it but I would like to use different paramenters to find categories, let me explain.

Suppose to have this Mysql table: (it is the same as reported in the behavior doc PLUS **slug** column:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id INTEGER(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    parent_id INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    lft INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    rght INTEGER(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
    slug VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

this slug column will have the real "path" of the category, example:

```
www.example.com/controller/action/slug
```

as you can see I need to pass the real name (not the number of the category) in the URL.

Then, my purpose is to retrieve all the TREE of that category (slug).

At the moment **TreeBehavior** filters categories by passing the ID. I cannot pass the ID, I need to pass the **slug**

The question is:

Can I still use TreeBehavior or do I have to extend it?

Thank you!

Comment: if you have the slug then you have the id as long as slug is unique within the tree. a simple select id from categories where slug = ... will give you the id

Comment: @SirRufo Yes, it is correct. But Do i have to implement it in my model not using the Behavior, is it follow the CakePHP rulues ? or Can I extends the TREE Behavior?

Comment: thinking cake the url should contain the slug id like e.g. www.example.com/controller/action/25/slug

Comment: @SirRufo yes, it should, but I do not want to put a number in the URL, i would like to create a URL like: www.example.com/controller/action/slug

Comment: i know that you don't want, but that is the cake way. if you don't want the cake way, you have to get back to cake manually. the behaviours follow the cake way

Comment: @SirRufo yes i know, i'm only asking if i can implement this method exending the behavior or in the model.

Comment: @SirRufo hmm i think about that! thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need the [SluggableTree behavior](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/sky_l3ppard/2009/09/13/sluggabletree-behavior-to-make-tree-based-slugs)